# import numpy on python 3.5 on mac osx

Tags: python, macos, numpy, installation

I tried to follow your advices about typing in `macport` :

```
cd /opt/local/bin 
sudo ./port install py35-numpy
```

and apparently it worked, but Python still doesn't find any module named `'numpy'`...

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in painlessly using Python with NumPy on Linux, Mac, or Windows, I'd highly suggest using the [miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html) distribution. Once it's installed, just open a terminal and run

```
$ conda install python=3.5 numpy
```

and you'll be ready to go. It also makes the rest of the scientific Python ecosystem similarly easy to install.